# Clarification about Ports in Kubernetes scaling

Tags: kubernetes

Let's say I have a web application Backend that I want to deploy with the help of Kubernetes, how exactly does scaling work in this case.

I understand scaling in Kubernetes as: We have one a master node that orchestrates multiple worker nodes where each of the worker nodes runs 0-n different containers with the same image. My question is, if this is correct, how does Kubernetes deal with the fact that the same application use the same Port within one worker node? Does the request reach the master node which then handles this problem internally?

Comment: Kubernetes has a somewhat complex internal networking environment, and each Pod and Service has its own IP address within the cluster-internal network.  The Kubernetes documentation on [Services](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/) might be helpful, and contains a couple of technical details that might explain the underlying mechanisms a little better.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, but it is correct that multiple instances of the same image can be deployed on the same worker node right?

Comment: Sure; you could have multiple Pods running the same image, or an injected sidecar container where pretty much every Pod is sharing the same image.  As a parallel, consider that it's also possible to be running multiple processes of the same executable in your desktop OS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does the request reach the master node which then handles this problem internally?

No, the master nodes does not handle traffic for your apps. Typically traffic meant for your apps arrive to a load balancer or gateway, e.g. [Google Cloud Load Balancer](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing) or [AWS Elastic Load Balancer](https://aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/), then the load balancer forwards the request to a replica of a matching service - this is managed by the [Kubernetes Ingress resource](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/) in your cluster.

The master nodes - the control plane - is only used for management, e.g. when you deploy a new image or service.

> how does Kubernetes deal with the fact that the same application use the same Port within one worker node?

Kubernetes uses a container runtime for your containers. You can try this on your own machine, e.g. when you use [docker](https://www.docker.com/), you can create multiple containers (instances) of your app, all listening on e.g. port 8080. This is a key feature of containers - the provide network isolation.

On Kubernetes, all containers are tied together with a custom container networking. How this works, depends on what [Container Networking Interface](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/extend-kubernetes/compute-storage-net/network-plugins/)-plugin you use in your cluster. Each Pod in your cluster will get its own IP address. All your containers can listen to the same port, if you want - this is an abstraction.